# Facebook: Using my drupal comments system and FB comments all at the same time, and storing comments inside my own site and not FB?

Tags: facebook, drupal, drupal-comments

I´ve just started to test, use and play with facebook apps. I´ve searched stackoverflow but didn´t find exactly what I need, so, here I am.
I´ve a drupal site. I´ve installed the Facebook for Drupal module, so I can use facebook in my site. I want users to be able to post comments in my site without creating for them any account.
I can use that module for that.

So, the question is: is there a way to allow people to use the default Drupal comment system, so when anonymous users want to comment they can post the comment directely to my site, or if they are logged with their FB account they can post comments as their FB user?
I want every time the comments to be posted inside my site, I mean to be hosted inside my own database. That´s why I don´t want to use disqus.

But I´ve read that you can use either Drupal comments OR FB comments. Are FB comments hosted inside FB and not my site?

As you can see, I´m not much into FB, so I don´t know much about it. I just want my users to be able to interact in my site with their FB accounts if they want.

Hope someone can help me out with some insight. Hope this question is clear enough... english isn´t my mother´s tongue and it was kinda hard to explain what I need :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use normal Drupal comments, and just allow people to log into your site using fb_connect.module from the [Drupal for Facebook](http://drupal.org/project/fb) module, or using the [Facebook Connect module](http://drupal.org/project/fbconnect). And of course allow anonymous commenting as well to meet your other requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I´ve already have that module installed, but when people log in with their FB account it takes it and shows their ID, but when I try to post a comments, it is posted as annon, and they have to fill in their information...

Comment: It seems that it is one thing or the other: I get the FB app to comment and, separately, the normal comments in my page... is there a way to integrate both? Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to use Facebook comments in your app—you should be creating user accounts based on Facebook Connect logins, and then just using normal Drupal comments. What you describe in your first comment in suggests that you don't have Facebook Connect working correctly.

Comment: Thanks! Hm, I think I´m beggining to roughly understand how this works: anonymous users cannot post "drupal comments" with thir FB accounts without registering to the site. Is thet correct?

Comment: That's right. They log into the site using their Facebook accounts, and then post non-anonymous comments.

Comment: Is there any way to do that without creating an account? I mean, something like: The comment form gets the information from the logged in FB user and post the comment as anonymous but adds the name and picture from the FB account. Something like the Gravatar module, that let´s people every time they post something using their registered gravatar email, to "get" the name and picture.